# jspdf-autotable - Multiple font colors in a table column text

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

JsPdf-autoTable is a very good pdf export software and very simple to work with.

Now, I want to add different font colors/style to a text in 1 of my columns.Like shown in the below image. But I can't figure out how I can add this.

[image: here the text is rendered in a column with multiple colors]

Is there an easy working example ?Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would have to use the hooks to write the text yourself.

Comment: @SimonBengtsson  - thanks.May I know the hooks and the usage I can use to render in the way I shown in the question?

Comment: Have you seen the examples in the repository? Let me know if you have a specific question how to use them.

Comment: @SimonBengtsson - Thanks for the tip. I have used the 'drawCell' hook and saved the positions of x and y and later used those positions to format my text.